# ACF block moving <style> to <head>

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using [ACF Blocks](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/blocks/) on a site I'm building.

I've registered my block via a plugin, like so:

```
<?php
function acf_blocks() {
    if( function_exists('acf_register_block_type') ) {
        acf_register_block_type(array(
            'name'              => 'intro-intro',
            'title'             => __('Page Intro'),
            'description'       => __('Page intro block'),
            'render_template'   => plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'template-parts/blocks/page-intro/page-intro.php',
            'category'          => 'formatting',
            'icon'              => 'editor-textcolor',
            'keywords'          => array( 'testimonial', 'quote' ),
        ));
    }
}
add_action('acf/init', 'acf_blocks');
```

Here's how it's looking in the `page-intro.php` template file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Page Intro Block Template.
 *
 * @param   array $block The block settings and attributes.
 * @param   string $content The block inner HTML (empty).
 * @param   bool $is_preview True during AJAX preview.
 * @param   (int|string) $post_id The post ID this block is saved to.
 */
?>
<div class="page-intro-wrapper">
    <div class="page-intro">    
        <?php
            $title = esc_html( get_field('title') );
            if( get_field('include_intro_text') == 'yes' ) {
                echo '<h2>'.$title.'</h2>'; 
                echo get_field('text');
            }
            else {
                echo '<h2 class="no-intro-text">'.$title.'</h2>';
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the field I've created via Field Groups in ACF settings:

[image: ACF Field Group]

The block works as expected apart from one thing. I'd like to add a background image to the `.page-intro-wrapper` class. To do this, I've created the following function within my plugin:

```
<?php
function page_intro_styles() {
    $background_image = get_field('background_image', get_the_ID() );
    ?>
        <style>
            .page-intro-wrapper {
                background: url( <?= wp_get_attachment_image_src($background_image, 'hero')[0]; ?> );
            }
            @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
                .page-intro-wrapper {
                    background: url( <?= wp_get_attachment_image_src($background_image, 'hero-2x')[0]; ?> ); 
                }
            }
        </style>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'page_intro_styles');
```

I was expecting this function to take the `$background_image` field from my block and display the image URL. The background image isn't showing up.

Using `var_dump($background_image);` prints NULL on the front end.

I've also tried `$background_image = get_field('background_image', get_queried_object_id() );`

What am I missing here?

Comment: What happens with the following: `var_dump(get_the_ID()); global $post, $wp_query; var_dump($post); var_dump($wp_query);`

Comment: Hey, @Tom  Here's what it prints `int(12) object(WP_Post)#1649 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(12) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2020-07-22 13:26:29" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2020-07-22 13:26:29" ["post_content"]=> string(8839)`

Answer (score 0):

`get_the_ID();` is outside the main loop in this case, so I think you're going to need to access the global $post variable. Here's the updated code:

```
<?php
function page_intro_styles() {

    // Get the global variable
    global $post;

    // Check to see if we have an ID. May also want to check is_single or is_page here as well.
    if(isset($post->ID)){

        // Use the global $post instead of template tag.
        $background_image = get_field('background_image', $post->ID );
        ?>
            <style>
                .page-intro-wrapper {
                    background: url( <?= wp_get_attachment_image_src($background_image, 'hero')[0]; ?> );
                }
                @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
                    .page-intro-wrapper {
                        background: url( <?= wp_get_attachment_image_src($background_image, 'hero-2x')[0]; ?> ); 
                    }
                }
            </style>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'page_intro_styles');
```

Comment: No dice. The full image path isn't loading: `background: url(im-jealous-of-your-microphone.local/);`

Comment: What comes from `print_r(background_image);` ?